# Should we trust on the answers found here for Islamic questions

Tags: discussion

Well I was thinking, though this site provides a ground to ask the Islamic questions here and get informed for what we seek, but should we accept and follow the replies we get here?

My personal thoughts are to first verify from the real books we got by the fine hard work of our Imam's. Though it might be difficult to find a solution in the books when we know very less, but the references we get from replies makes us easy to narrow our search and we can get a solid proof which can't be denied easily by anyone.

Comment: Whether something is accepted by a person or not that is up to them to choose, if something has sources and citations provided and can be easily verified through authentic sources and scholars then I see no reason not to accept it, but again it is up to the person.

Comment: All I mean to say is for the `new comers` of Islam and the ones who may start trusting the sites more than the trusted means, to verify what you get from here. Sites are not the authentic grounds to accept the answers on the fly. We have resources that are much more trustworthy.

Comment: I do not disagree :)

Answer (score 4):

This is from the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic);

> It is also important to note that this is not a fatwa site. While
>   questions on the legality of actions (from an Islamic perspective) are
>   welcome, answers may be posted by anybody regardless of training or
>   expertise. It is important to judge the evidences provided by each
>   answer to the best of your own abilities, and accept such answers at
>   your own risk.

To sum up, judge the evidences and accept answers at your own risk.

Comment: I think we can make it even more explicit [like Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:General_disclaimer). E.g. we can add something like _"Please be advised that nothing found here has necessarily been reviewed by people with the expertise required to provide you with complete, accurate or reliable information. We cannot guarantee the validity of the information found on the site. If you need specific advice please seek a professional who is licensed or knowledgeable in that area."_ to the [tour] or [help/on-topic].

Comment: @kaveh, this is what I was demanding, but instead of the help center, I guess it is better to be displayed on every Q/A page as a banner so people be informed. Because, I guess very few will be going through the `help` center or the `tour`

Comment: @MTM, I feel it would be annoying to show it on every post but more importantly that is not something we can do: moderators can only edit [help/on-topic] and the top part of [tour].